# How to set "Do Not Check Spelling or Grammar" for a section in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, format, spell-check, code, pycharm

Today I'm trying to copy-paste some code from PyCharm to Word. It works, as PyCharm preformats it as HTML, but it lights up like Christmas lights due to the fact that half of my code doesn't follow spelling rules. Is there any way to mark these sections without using a format, due to the fact that when I try to use a format, it removes the custom HTML formatting and it therefore loses all the relevant syntax highlighting?

Thanks!